# Are there any documented best practices for in-app SaaS upgrade prompts?

Tags: payment, accounts

I have a SaaS web app with 3 different plans.  Each plan increases access to certain features or a large quantity of a particular feature.  We'll call them A, B and C with C being the highest level, most expensive plan.

Currently if you are signed up for plan A you may see a location in the application that says "Upgrade your account to get access to XYZ feature" (because plan A doesn't include that feature). Clicking on that prompt takes you to the plan management view where you can see the features vs plans and upgrade if you wish.

What I'm wondering is whether the prompts on the lower plans are overwhelming the user's experience calling out things to them that they don't have access to, and wondering if there are any best practices on how to handle this?

For example if I remove the prompts completely, the user may not know that the next level plan has a feature they need and want; perhaps they cancel because of that.

Should the prompts be removed and replaced with email marketing telling the user about what they are missing out on?

Whats the best way to handle?

Comment: Please check this question, which might of been answered already. https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/17897/upgrade-friendly-visual-treatment-for-features-disabled-in-the-free-version-of-a. You should also check this article "SaaS Pricing: Features that Make People Upgrade" https://blog.kissmetrics.com/make-people-upgrade/. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I like keeping the up-sell right within the context of using the product. You aren't forcing the user to click on something before they find out it isn't available and you aren't hiding the functionality either. But of which could lead to more frustration than seeing the up-sell prompts.

If you are concerned about it being overwhelming for users maybe you can run an experiment to compare your upgrades/churn/satisfaction using the email strategy vs. all the in-app prompts.

(Just realized this was from 4yrs ago :)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that in your SaaS web app the user from plan A is able to navigate to the pages where XYZ features are held. When occupying the restricted page you can make use of the white space by giving a value prop so that they will be more convinced to upgrade.

The bottom line is, make sure the restricted features are never hidden. They are always there and appear as they would on plan C however when the user tries to interact with them they get directed to the upgrade prompt.